# Speed up a series of perl -pi commands

Tags: regex, perl

As part of a wider script I use a series of perl -pi commands to get rid of various artefacts and mistypings in LaTeX.

The snippet is this:

```
perl -pi -e "s/”/\''/g" *.txt
perl -pi -e "s/“/\`\`/g" *.txt
perl -pi -e "s/,/, /g" *.txt
perl -pi -e "s/ ,/,/g" *.txt
perl -pi -e "s/ !/!/g" *.txt
perl -pi -e "s/\&/ and /g" *.txt
perl -pi -e "s/\n/\n\n/g" *.txt
perl -pi -e "s/\\\\em/\\\\em /g" *.txt
perl -pi -e "s/’/'/g" *.txt
perl -pi -e "s/\*\*\*/\\\\split/g" *.txt
```

*.txt is about 50-80 files and this snippet takes a surprisingly long time to run - I suspect that putting the set into a proper perl script will improve the effectiveness. My question is: what method in perl has the quickest execution time for a set of simple replacements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -i -pe'
   s/”/\x27\x27/g;
   s/“/``/g;
   s/,/, /g;
   ...
' *.txt
```

But, that still scans every line a million times. The following avoids that:

```
perl -i -pe'
   BEGIN {
      %tr = (
         "”" => "\x27\x27",
         "“" => "``",
         "," => ", ",
         ...
      );
      $pat = join "|", map quotemeta, keys(%tr);
   }
   s/($pat)/$tr{$1}/g;
' *.txt
```

Comment: Awesome - is there something odd about the join statment? I get "Not enough arguments for join or string at -e line 12, at EOF
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at -e line 12." :(

Comment: @Joe, Bad quoting on my part. Used `'` inside of `perl -e'...'` without properly escaping it. Fixed

Comment: By the way, I used `\x27` and `"` instead of `'`, since they are far more readable than `'\''` or `'"'"'` that would otherwise be needed to escape `'`.

Comment: Excellent - always nice to learn something extra! Also - this does appear to have solved my problem! accepted. :)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to make replacements in one pass instead of ten,

script.pl

---

```
  s/”/\''/g;
  s/“/\`\`/g;
  s/,/, /g;
  s/ ,/,/g;
  s/ !/!/g;
  s/\&/ and /g;
  s/\n/\n\n/g;
  s/\\\\em/\\\\em /g;
  s/’/'/g;
  s/\*\*\*/\\\\split/g;
```

execute script,

```
perl -pi script.pl *.txt
```

Comment: You could probably get away without escaping the apostrophes and backticks.

Comment: @JimDavis yes, I could but it was mere copy/paste.

Answer (score 2):

Just pull all substitutions into a single line:

```
perl -pi -e "s/”/\''/g; s/“/\`\`/g; s/,/, /g; s/ ,/,/g; s/ !/!/g; s/\&/ and /g; s/\n/\n\n/g; s/\\\\em/\\\\em /g; s/’/'/g; s/\*\*\*/\\\\split/g" *.txt
```

Reading, writing and parsing file only once will certainly be much faster than doing it many times.